# How to disable an onclick option in span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this

```
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"  id="icon" runat="server"  ></span>
```

I dont use onclick but my icon is clickable (maybe because the jquery-ui class...)
I need to disable the onclick completely.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you want the cursor to be like same or what ?

Comment: i need the hover from the jquery ui plugin to be diseable ( i think..)

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: i have created i cant see any hover or click changes occurrence here http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/768/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the clicking on the span does not fire any event if not specified, means this is more a design issue

If there is a hand-cursor coming up as soon as you hover you can spcecify this by the cursor attribute in css:

```
.someclass {
   cursor: default
}
```

Another possibility if there is some event fireing as seen here:
[Use CSS to make a span not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144050/use-css-to-make-a-span-not-clickable)

```
<span class='unclickable' onclick='return false;'>description<br></span>
```

Comment: Thank you! the - onclick='return false;' worked for me

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

jQuery `off()` to off the onclick event for specific span.

Use:

`jQuery( "span#icon" ).off("click");`

Check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp) tutorial for this

Or, You can try:

```
jQuery( "span#icon" ).css("cursor","default");
```

Answer (score 0):

i am new in stackoverflow. i am trying to add my code here but i am failed for that reason i just added picture here with my Html code 
[image]
and script are 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a clickable span:
html:

```
<span class="clickable-span">View</span>
```

css:

```
.clickable-span {
    color: darkcyan;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
}
.clickable-span:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

For a Unclickable span:
html:

```
<span class="unclickable-span">View</span>
```

css:

```
.unclickable-span{
    color: cyan;   
    cursor: default;
}
```