# Is it possible to apply same style to element 1 and element 2, without calling out the style in element 1?

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply same style to element 1 and element 2, without calling out the style in element 1?

Element 1 is `.notch`

Element 2 is `#fullbg`

Element 1 must always come before Element 2. I would like to apply Element 2's bg-color to Element 1 and Element 2.

How do I make the first `<div class="notch">`have a yellow bg (#fullbg), without applying any specific style (class/id) to `<div class="notch">`?

I'm thinking this could be done with :nth-of-type() selector...? Eventually, I will have several "notches", with `<div id="fullbg3">`, `<div id="fullbg4">`, etc.

Check codepen example - I want first notch to be yellow (like fullbg), and second notch to be red (like fullbg2), without giving any notch their own special class.

Currently, the first notch is red. It should be yellow.

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/GqJGxb

HTML

```
<p>stuff</p>
<div class="notch">this should be YELLOW</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div id="fullbg">this should be YELLOW</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div class="notch">this should be RED</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div id="fullbg2">this should be RED</div>
```

CSS

```
.notch,
#fullbg {
    background: yellow;
}

.notch,
#fullbg2 {
    background: red;
}
```

Here is, more specifically what I'm trying to achieve: the bgcolor and small block color should match. codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/rLVrJo

Comment: Here is, more specifically what I'm trying to achieve: the bgcolor and small block color should match. http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/rLVrJo

Answer (score 1):

The `~` (selects successors) partly solves the problem, though it can be not very flexible sometimes (i.e. you have to right that for every new "notch").

```css
.notch,#fullbg{
  background:yellow;
}
#fullbg~.notch,#fullbg2{
  background:red;
}
#fullbg2~.notch,#fullbg3{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<p>stuff</p>
<div class="notch">this should be YELLOW</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div id="fullbg">this should be YELLOW</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div class="notch">this should be RED</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div id="fullbg2">this should be RED</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div class="notch">this should be GREEN</div>

<p>stuff</p>
<div id="fullbg3">this should be GREEN</div>
```

Comment: I applied your styles to my actual code. The yellow is applied. But add a "2" then "3" to <div class="fullwidth-header"></div>, and the small block stays yellow. I need it to match bgcolor. http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/MewBbG

Comment: Try changing this to say: <div class="fullwidth-header2"> ------ the yellow is still there, but should now change to be red (to match red bg). http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/MewBbG

Comment: I have assumed that you have the sequence, you haven't told that it should work separately. I have misunderstood you, sorry, @Goatsy.

Comment: no, don't be sorry - i'm sorry i wasn't specific enough... :) can you help me solve this without having to write a new notch? it has to be same notch every time.

Comment: @Goatsy Then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792) may help you, appears that it is essentially "previous sibling selector" problem.

Comment: No, there is no "previous sibling selector", but using `flex` you can make it work as if there were

Comment: @LGSon Ive tried using flex before, but it interfered with other parts of my design. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated based on comment/codepen sample*

Here is a start

```css
/* notch nav styles */
.notch-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.notch-nav li {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 33px;
    /* adjust this line to push entire notch nav down and away from minilinks */    
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.notch-nav a {
    display: block;
    /* padding:50px 0 20px 30px; */    
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: #cca134;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.notch-nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: @295pms;
}

.notch-nav .current .dropdown:hover .dropbtn:before,
.notch-nav .current .dropdown:hover .dropbtn:after {
    display: none
}
.notch-nav .current .dropdown-content a:before,
.notch-nav .current .dropdown-content a:after {
    display: none
}
.notch-nav .current a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 5;
}
.notch-nav .current a:before,
.notch-nav .current a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
/* make fullwidth-header 100% */
.fullwidth-header {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
}
.fullwidth-header-block {
    display: block;
    background: @white;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 53px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.fullwidth-header-block p {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

/*  current classes  */
.curr1 li:nth-child(1),
.curr1 ~ div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background:blue;
  display: block;
}

.curr2 li:nth-child(2),
.curr2 ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background:black;
  display: block;
}

.curr3 li:nth-child(3),
.curr3 ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background:pink;
  display: block;
}

.curr4 li:nth-child(4),
.curr4 ~ div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background:green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav notch-nav curr4">
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn" href="/utilities/about-rpu">About</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn" href="/utilities/?q=contractors">Contractors</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn" href="/utilities/?q=businesses">Businesses</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn" href="/utilities/?q=residents">Residents</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="fullwidth-header">
  About
</div>

<div class="fullwidth-header">
  Contractors
</div>

<div class="fullwidth-header">
  Businesses
</div>

<div class="fullwidth-header">
  Residents
</div>
```

Comment: The "notch" is not present in your code, and i am unable to wrap them. See this codepen to get a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve: http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/rLVrJo (small block and bg-color should match)

Comment: @Goatsy Updated my answer with one way to go ... also check out answers given in this question of mine, for optional ways to trigger groups of elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162805/toggle-radio-input-using-css-only

Comment: @Goatsy If my answer solved it, please accept, or else let me know what's missing.

Comment: Sorry - I have not yet had a chance to implement this. Let me get back to you in a few days.