# Disable an icon based on condition in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, function, icons, conditional-statements, title

I have an icon in a td which i wan to disable based on condition :

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><span 
                                            ng-disabled="action.isActionInprogress"
                                            ng-click="showAction($event,action)"
                                            style="cursor: pointer;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"                                           
                                            title="{{action.isActionInProgress ? 'Cannot View While Action In Progress' : 'Show Action'}}">
```

It shows the title (Cannot View While Action In Progress) but the icon doesn't get disabled.
What am i missing?

Comment: ng-disabled adds a disabled attribute to an element when the value evaluates to true. Is there styling configured to display the icon differently when the disabled attribute is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the span with a button and try. I don't think you can apply ng-disable for span directly. Else You have to dynamically apply style and prevent the click event to make span disable

```
<button class="btn"  ng-disabled="action.isActionInprogress"  ng-click="showAction($event,action)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" ></span></button>
```

[Use CSS to make a span not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144050/use-css-to-make-a-span-not-clickable)